# A* Path following with certain step size different from grid size

Tags: java, a-star

I have this method:

```
public boolean moveTowardsPoint(Point p, double stepSize, double minDistance, ArrayList<GameBodyObject> objects,  boolean shouldStepInto, AStar astar) {

    ArrayList<GameBodyObject> others = (ArrayList<GameBodyObject>) objects.clone();
    others.remove(this);

    if(aStarPath == null || lastPointToMove == null || !lastPointToMove.isAlmostTheSame(p, 0.01)) {
        try {
            astar.getGrid().unsetObstacleForObject(this);
            aStarPath = astar.process(this, p, objects);
            Collections.reverse(aStarPath);
            currentIndex = 0;
            current = null;
            astar.getGrid().reset();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    lastPointToMove = p.clone();

    double dx = p.getX() - getPosition().getX();
    double dy = p.getY() - getPosition().getY();

    Point lastPosition = getPosition().clone();

    boolean isClose = false;
    double dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (dist < Math.max(minDistance, stepSize)) {
        isClose = true;
    } else {
        if(aStarPath.indexOf(current) >= aStarPath.size() - 1) {

            if(shouldStepInto && dist <= stepSize) {
                setPosition(p.clone());
            }

        } else if(aStarPath != null && aStarPath.size() > 0) {
            if (current == null) {
                currentIndex = 0;
                current = aStarPath.get((int)currentIndex);
            }
            double mss = stepSize / current.getWidth();
            Spot p2 = aStarPath.get(Math.min((int)Math.ceil(currentIndex + mss), aStarPath.size() - 1));
            Spot p1 = current;
            if(!p1.equals(p2)) {
                Vector v = new Vector(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), p2.getY() - p1.getY()).normalize();
                getPosition().moveByVector(v.mult(stepSize));
                setRotation(v.getAngle());
            }
            currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + mss, aStarPath.size() - 1);
            current = aStarPath.get((int)currentIndex);
        }
    }
    return isClose;
}
```

It's a `GameBodyObject`'s method.

It should calculate A* path and move towards a point on that path however it does move slower than a `current`(`currentIndex`) moves forward through the path. I have there some distance checking at the beginning but that's not important. I move `currentIndex` by the amount of `stepSize` divided by the `grid cell size`. In my case it's `0.6`. Then I have a `moveByVector` method which simply moves a `Point` by the vector.

How to make it synchronous so that it moves as fast as `current`(`currentIndex`)? Is it even possible?

**EDIT**

Here are my variables definitions:

```
private List<Spot> aStarPath = null;
private Spot current = null;
private double currentIndex = -1;
private Point lastPointToMove;
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a one mistake in that solution. On diagonals the `currentIndex` growed faster than the player moved. So you have to take in account the angle in which the player is moving along that path. Concretely this:

```
  double coef = Math.max(Math.abs(Math.cos(angle)),Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)));
  double mss = stepSize / (current.getWidth() / coef);
```

The full method now looks like this and works like a charm:

```
public boolean moveTowardsPoint(Point p, double stepSize, double minDistance, ArrayList<GameBodyObject> objects,  boolean shouldStepInto, AStar astar) {

    ArrayList<GameBodyObject> others = (ArrayList<GameBodyObject>) objects.clone();
    others.remove(this);

    if(aStarPath == null || lastPointToMove == null || !lastPointToMove.isAlmostTheSame(p, 0.01)) {
        try {
            astar.getGrid().unsetObstacleForObject(this);
            aStarPath = astar.process(this, p, objects);
            Collections.reverse(aStarPath);
            currentIndex = 0;
            current = null;
            astar.getGrid().reset();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    lastPointToMove = p.clone();

    double dx = p.getX() - getPosition().getX();
    double dy = p.getY() - getPosition().getY();

    Point lastPosition = getPosition().clone();

    boolean isClose = false;
    double dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (dist < Math.max(minDistance, stepSize)) {
        isClose = true;
    } else {
        if(aStarPath.indexOf(current) >= aStarPath.size() - 1) {

            if(shouldStepInto && dist <= stepSize) {
                setPosition(p.clone());
            }

        } else if(aStarPath != null && aStarPath.size() > 0) {
            if (current == null) {
                currentIndex = 0;
                current = aStarPath.get((int)currentIndex);
            }
            Spot c1 = aStarPath.get((int)currentIndex);
            Spot c2 = aStarPath.get(Math.min((int)currentIndex + 1, aStarPath.size() - 1));
            double angle = new Vector(c2.getX() - c1.getX(),c2.getY() - c1.getY()).getAngle();
            double coef = Math.max(Math.abs(Math.cos(angle)),Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)));
            double mss = stepSize / (current.getWidth() / coef);
            Spot p2 = aStarPath.get(Math.min((int)Math.ceil(currentIndex + mss), aStarPath.size() - 1));
            Spot p1 = current;
            if(!p1.equals(p2)) {
                Vector v = new Vector(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), p2.getY() - p1.getY()).normalize();
                getPosition().moveByVector(v.mult(stepSize));
                setRotation(v.getAngle());
            }
            currentIndex = Math.min(currentIndex + mss, aStarPath.size() - 1);
            current = aStarPath.get((int)currentIndex);
        }
    }

    return isClose;
}
```